# Meaning of 相当おしゃれしてる

Tags: keigo, reading-comprehension

After a discussion on the fact that  おり姫 and ひこ星 can only meet once a year:

> 「おり姫なんて、朝から相当おしゃれしてるだろうね」
>   From morning, princess Ori ?????
>   「もう大変だろうな、そりゃ」
>   It's probably really tough.

I can't figure out what 相当おしゃれしてる means. I suspect it's some sort of 敬語 thing but it's beyond me.

Comment: This is actually really close to the imperative/continuative form of 「おっしゃる」 but the 「してる」 gives it away

Comment: btw I feel おり姫 is one word as a whole to be the proper name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

おしゃれ(する) means "to make up and/or dress up"
している is the present progressive of する.
相当 to a great extent

> I suspect it's some sort of 敬語 thing

No.